# Python equivalent of Matlab's hist3

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, histogram

```
for i=1:n
    centersX(:,i)=linspace(min(xData)+dX/2,max(xData)-dX/2,nbins)';
    centersY(:,i)=linspace(min(yData)+dY/2,max(phase)-dY/2,nbins)';

    centers = {centersX(:,i),centersY(:,i)};
    H(:,:,i) = hist3([xData yData],centers);
end
```

In each iteration, I construct `centersX` and `centersY` with `linspace` function. I then store them in a 2x1 cell array called `centers`. H is a nbins X nbins X n struct. In each iteration I fill a nbins X nbins slice of H with the data from hist3.

I'm looking for the Python equivalent. I'm having trouble with passing the arguments for `numpy.histogram2d`:

```
H[:,:,i] = numpy.histogram2d(xData,yData,centers)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 714, in histogramdd
    N, D = sample.shape
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 36, in <module>
    H[:,:,i] = numpy.histogram2d(xData, yData, centers)
  line 714, in histogram2d
    hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights)
  line 718, in histogramdd
    N, D = sample.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Since Python doesn't have cell arrays, I changed centers to be an array of arrays where `centers[0] = centersX` and `centers[1] = centersY`. What do I need to change such that that assuming the data are the same between matlab and python that the outputs will match?

EDIT:
I have also tried `H[:,:,i] = numpy.histogram2d(xData,yData, bins=(centersX,centersY))` to cutout the combining step into `centers` but no luck.

Comment: What are the types of `xData`, `yData`, `centersX`, and `centersY`?

Comment: @Eric float64. I have not casted them to anything after using numpy constructors

Comment: So they're `ndarray`s? Of what `.shape`?

Comment: yes `ndarray` of `.shape` (nbins,n)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combing them with square brackets?

Maybe you can also use [matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d).

```
H[:,:,i], *_ = numpy.histogram2d(xData,yData,bins=[centers[0], centers[1]])
H[:,:,i], *_ = matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d(xData,yData,bins=[centers[0], centers[1]])
```

In both, the values in centers are the bin edges, not the centers. You have to adjust the calculation. I think it is enough to remove the dX/2:

```
centersX(:,i)=linspace(min(xData),max(xData),nbins)';
centersY(:,i)=linspace(min(yData),max(phase),nbins)';
```